# A neural network to learn the connection between two totally different type of images

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, training, deep-neural-networks, neural-architecture-search

I have a dataset of two different type of images. Say, I have **images of a person** and **his all 10 fingerprints**. I want to create a relation between them to predict one from another. How I can do that and which architecture is suitable for this problem or similar type of problem.

Comment: I doubt you can predict a fingerprint image from a person's face, but this is still a valid question for some other datasets.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a pair of separate deep image embeddings with a [contrastive loss](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/losses/ContrastiveLoss). The idea is similar to the [Siamese network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_neural_network) architecture. In Siamese networks the pairs of images are of the same type - so both input images are fed through the copy of the same network. In your case the images are of different kinds, so I would just have separate nets for person images and fingerprints.